# How do I get the state of the parent component in a child styled component using tagged template literals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a react component `App` as following, it has a state `WHRatio`, and my `div` component will use the `WHRatio` value to calculate the `height` value. In my following way, it can work, it can get the parent component state `WHRatio` successfully.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const sizeWidth = 100;
  const [WHRatio, setWHRatio] = useState(1);

  const getContainerHeight = () => Math.floor(sizeWidth / WHRatio);

  const incWHRatio = () => setWHRatio(WHRatio + 1);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          width: sizeWidth,
          height: getContainerHeight(),
          backgroundColor: "orange"
        }}
      >
      </div>
      <button onClick={incWHRatio}>Inc WHRatio</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

As we known, `styled-components` utilises tagged template literals to style the components.

```js
// something like this
const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
`
```

I want to use the tagged template literals to style my component rather than the inline style. So how do I get the state of the parent component in a child styled component using tagged template literals?

[Online Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-neumann-grl5i?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that by passing props value to custom style, for example:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: ${props => props.customHeight + "px"}
`
```

Full Example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: ${props => props.customHeight + "px"}
`

export default function App() {
  const sizeWidth = 100;
  const [WHRatio, setWHRatio] = useState(1);

  const getContainerHeight = () => Math.floor(sizeWidth / WHRatio);

  const incWHRatio = () => setWHRatio(WHRatio + 1);

  return (
    <>
      <Container
        customHeight={getContainerHeight()} 
      ></Container>
      <button onClick={incWHRatio}>Inc WHRatio</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Also, you can use css feature and pass it to styled component, for more details and examples you can check this [url](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs).

Example 2:

```
import styled, { css, keyframes } from 'styled-components'

const animation = keyframes`
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100 {
    opacity: 1;
  }
`

const animationRule = css`
  ${animation} 1s infinite alternate;
`

const Component = styled.div`
  animation: ${animationRule};
`
```

[DEMO URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-bouman-rz69w)

Comment: The first way you mentioned is what I want. However, I am not sure how the second way css feature works. Could you provide more details? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, Answer updated. thank you

Answer (score 0):

did you try some like this :

you pass your sizeWidth like

```
<Container sizeWidth={sizeWidth}/>
```

then in your styled component will be like:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  width: ${(props) => props.sizeWidth + "px"};
`
```